# Equal inner gaps between table-cell columns

Tags: jquery, html, css, grid

I am using [savvior.org](http://savvior.org/) to create a grid based layout for images and other elements, everything works fine, I am only stuck with adding inner gaps between the `.columns`.

The outcome is currently as follows:

[image]

As you can see the gap is equal but the height of the elements within the row isn't.

I tried to use borders, I manged to get the elements the same height but then the gaps didn't have an equal space...

Note, the gab/padding need to be adjustable.

I have put together a JSFiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/6n0wasjf/4/

Here is the CSS:

```
/*GRID SYSTEM =================================================================*/
.grid {
    width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  position: relative;
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
  opacity: 0;
}
.grid .grid { 
    opacity: 1;
} 
.grid:last-of-type {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

    .grid .column {
      padding: 0 10px;
      display: table-cell;
    }

    .grid .column:first-of-type {
      padding-left: 0;
    }

    .grid .column:last-of-type {
     padding-right: 0;
    }

    /*Columns width settings*/
    .grid .size-1of1 {
      width: 100%
    }
    .grid .size-1of2 {
      width: 50%;
    }
    .grid .size-1of3 {
      width: 33.33%;
    }
    .grid .size-1of4 {
      width: 25%;
    }
    .grid .size-1of5 {
        width: 20%;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue is due to removing `padding` in `.grid .column:first-of-type` and `.grid .column:last-of-type`. It will cause width difference for `.column` divs.

Instead add negative margin for `.grid` to remove left and right padding.

```
.grid {
    ....
   margin-left: -5px;
   margin-right: -5px;
}
```

Please check the fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/afelixj/6n0wasjf/5/

Comment: yes.. but the left padding for the first column div, and right padding for last column div will push the content in.

Comment: Don't understand sorry

Comment: In your css there is no margin for grid, and there is no left padding for first column. so it is aligned to the left of the page.  I have added negative margin to the grid which will move grid to left, but added left padding to first column which will push the content to right.

Comment: the whole .grid is moved to the left leaving a gab on the right tho

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79644/discussion-between-leo-and-afelixj).